# copy directories with matching string and all sub-directories and files

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I've got a beginner question. I'm trying to use XCOPY to copy all directories beginning with the string "44*" and all files and sub-directories within, regardless of their names.

I've got this to work to grab the appropriate files, but the directory structure isn't coming along.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/ad 
"C:\sourcepathgoeshere\44*" ') do xcopy /s /i /v 
"C:\sourcepathgoeshere\%%a\*" 
C:\destinationpath
```

I was able to copy the structure first with `/t`, but that just made a bunch of empty directories with all the files beneath.

Thanks for help putting these basic pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do xcopy /s /i /v "C:\sourcepathgoeshere\%%a*" "C:\destinationpath\%%a"

You don't really specify what the problem you have is. The change I've made above works for me, generating

```
c:\destinationpath\44-abc\(filetree from 44-abc)
c:\destinationpath\44-xyz\(filetree from 44-xyz)
```

IOW, a copy of only the directories from the source that start `44`.

It's also required that the `xcopy` commands all be on a single physical line.

I'm not happy about the linebreak in the middle of the `dir` statement. It appears to work, but I'd break it between `'` and `)`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for and I can clearly see how it's working now. Sorry about the sloppy copy/paste above if it made things confusing.